# How to get the starting and ending rownum when using EXCEL Autofilter function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How to get the starting and ending rownum when using excel Autofilter function in VBA.

I have a set of 500k+ records. and use filters on a particular column. Due to this because of filters the starting rownum might change since other records are hidden in autofilter

so on using the autofilter i might end with startrow as 74562 and ending 87000.

Can someone show a macro which could output the startrow and endrow for every filter I use.

The data is sorted so any filter would be a fixed consecutive bunch

**EDIT:**
I have realized that the following code gives the result but in range

```
 MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A81000").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
```

It shows result as `$A$73351:$A$77343`. But I just want the 73351 in `StartRow` variable and `77343` in `EndRow` variable. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask how to return the row number of the first and last row in a range. This is how:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim StartRow As Long
Dim EndRow As Long

Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A81000").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
' r is now $A$73351:$A$77343

StartRow = r.Row ' returns 73351
EndRow = r.Row + r.Rows.Count - 1 ' returns 77343
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim rRange as Range
    Set rRange = Range("A1")    
    Debug.Print rRange.Offset(1, 0).Row
    Debug.Print rRange.Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: i want to skip the first record as it contains headers...would the above encompass for the same?

Comment: The above macro returns the endrow correct but the startrow is showing 2 even though the range of rows visible after applying autofilter is A72500:A80000 :((

Comment: Yes you're right. That surprises me. You'll need to use something with SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) as per JMax's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this piece of code:

```
Sub Get_Filtered_Range()
Dim oWS As Worksheet
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oColRng As Range
Dim oInRng As Range

oWS = ActiveSheet
'Trigger any autofilter if needed
'oWS.UsedRange.AutoFilter(Field:=2, Criteria1:="Test")
oRng = oWS.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
oColRng = oWS.Range("A2:A"&ActiveSheet.Rows.Count)
oInRng = Intersect(oRng, oColRng)

'display the values in the VBEditor
Debug.Print("Filtered Range is " & oInRng.Address)
Debug.Print("First Row Filtered Range is " & oInRng.Rows(1).Row)
End Sub
```

Adapted from [here](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2008/08/retrieve-get-first-row-of-excel.html)